# Allow atomic update to the database

Tags: yii

Given several model classes like

```
car, supplier, ...
```

we have save() method for each of them.

What i want to achieve is that, i want to save
`car and supplier` 
models, and if one of models failed, none are saved.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: In C# .Net I will use 'Transaction' or 'TransactionScope' for this... Not sure about yii..

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for transactions. Have a look here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#using-transaction-with-ar

```
$transaction=$model->dbConnection->beginTransaction();
if($car->save() && $supplier->save()) {
    $transaction->commit();
} else {
    $transaction->rollback();
}
```